# Как распарсить пользовательские теги

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, парсер

Есть строка вида:

> какой-то текст [Tagname="param1"]some text[/Tagname] какой-то другой текст

Нужно средствами PHP распарсить текст, выцепить из него каждую подобную конструкцию, и записать каждую в словарь вида:

```
[
  ['name' => 'Tagname', 'param' => 'param1', 'data' => 'some text'],
  ...
]
```

Я пытался сделать так, чтоб для начала распарсить хотя-бы только открывающие теги:

```
$string1 = "some text[AAA=\"bbb\"]some stuff[/AAA]some more text[sdfsf=\"bbb\"]some stuff[/sdfsf] sdfsdfsdfs";

$reg1 = "#\[[A-z]\=\"[A-z]\"\]#";
$matches = [];
preg_match_all($reg1, $string1, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

но совпадения с шаблоном в массив не выводятся. видно только один пустой элемент. Может preg_match_all делает что-то не то что я себе представляю, и нужно юзать какие-то другие функции?

Comment: `[A-z]+`, иначе всего 1 буква должна быть. Да, и интервал `A-z` это не только латинские буквы.

Comment: Делал когда-то парсер BB-кодов. Регулярки - это плохой ход. Парсите по вхождениям `[`, что-то типа `strpos('[')`.

Comment: @Other, лучше регулярок для парсинга бб-кодов ни чего нет. Иначе замучаешься правила писать.

Comment: Да нет, добротное AST весьма просто пишется.

Comment: @Other, и даже то что у параметров могут быть кавычки как одинарные, так и двойные, а может вообще не быть; внутри параметров могут быть те же самые кавычки в которые они заключены, а так же закрывающиеся квадратные скобки; а параметров может быть штук 10-11 в перемешку?

Answer (score 2):

Вообще если есть  возможность используйте тэкги html.
Если нет то надо писать алгоритм парсера:

1. берём открывающийся тэг. ложим в стэк
2. ищем закрывающий тэг. ложим в стэк
3. если есть параметры парсим их т.е. это име параметра и после имени есть равно и две кавычки ' или " но ни как '" не разные. Ложим в стэк
4. по этому принципу проверяем валидность тэгов т.е. количество элементов в стеке должно делиться на 2-ва без остатка.
5. Далее с стэка забираем нужные нам значения

https://github.com/jbowens/jBBCode - хороший пример реализации.

p.s. регулярка не подходит по нескольким причинам:

1. нельзя проверить валидность данных.
2. уязвимость таких решений
3. скорость, регулярки это медленно и ресурсоёмко т.к. регулярка проходит рекурсивно по символьно так что сложность от O^2 до O^n в зависимости от патерна.

Comment: Про регулярки полное вранье!